# Jquery executing/triggering same code on different events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-trigger

I have this function onclick event of custom tag `densitybtn='yes'`

```
$("[densitybtn='yes']").on('click', function () {
    var no_of_people = 0;
    //calcdensity
    $("[calcdensity='yes']").each(function () {
        no_of_people = parseInt($(this).val()) + no_of_people;
    });
    var total_density = parseInt(carpetArea) / parseInt(no_of_people);
    $("#densityVal").html(Myval);
});
```

Can i extend same code by extending it to $("[calcdensity='yes']").on('blur')

```
$("[calcdensity='yes']").on('blur').$("[densitybtn='yes']").on('click', function () {

});
```

Am not sure on executing same code on different events

Let me know is this method correct? or is there any alternative way available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the function normally (not as an anonymous function) and pass the function to the event listeners

```
function listener() {
   var no_of_people = 0;
   //calcdensity
   $("[calcdensity='yes']").each( function() {
      no_of_people = parseInt($(this).val())+no_of_people;
   });
   var total_density = parseInt(carpetArea)/parseInt(no_of_people);
   $("#densityVal").html(Myval);
}

$("[densitybtn='yes']").on('click', listener);
$("[calcdensity='yes']").on('blur', listener);
```

Comment: the second call should be on('blur')

Answer (score 0):

Nope, thats not a good practise. 
Instead you can write a function for the second intent and call it on blur of `$("[calcdensity='yes']")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind multiple events using jQuery's [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) by space-separating the event arguments.

```
$("[densitybtn='yes']").on('click blur', function() {
    // actions to perform
})
```

You can bind events to multiple elements using jQuery's [`.add()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("[densitybtn='yes']").add("[calcdensity='yes']").on('click blur', function() {
    // actions to perform
})
```

Comment: I have to manage  [calcdensity='yes'] and [densitybtn='yes']. How can we add  [calcdensity='yes']?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Do you want to run the function on both 'click' and 'blur' for both  [calcdensity='yes'] and [densitybtn='yes'], or just 'click' for the first and 'blur' for the second?